# Derby connection error: ERROR XBM0H: Directory /usr/opt/derby/db-derby-10.12.1.1-bin/bin/MyDbTest cannot be created

Tags: jdbc, derby

I am trying to setup Derby on my Mac following these instructions... [Tutorial](https://db.apache.org/derby/papers/DerbyTut/ij_intro.html)

When I try to run `connect 'jdbc:derby:MyDbTest;create=true';` in ij I get the following error

`ERROR XJ041: Failed to create database 'MyDbTest', see the next exception for details.`
`ERROR XBM0H: Directory /usr/opt/derby/db-derby-10.12.1.1-bin/bin/MyDbTest cannot be created.`

I have tried googling this error a bit now with no success...

I also get a `thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/derby/tools/ij` when trying to run as super user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be a Permissions issue, try running all these commands throught a directory you have full permissions to such as `~/Documents/Derby`.